# Spring MVC equivalent of .Net MVC LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I am coming from a ASP.Net MVC world where Microsoft provides the LinkExtensions.ActionLink method in Razor (their version of JSP) to generate anchor element (a element) to a specific controller/action.

The concept is pretty simple:  the Razor (JSP) code references the controller and action, the ActionLink function does the hard work of generating the correct URI to get to that controller/action.

Is there anything like this in Spring MVC?

Comment: The Java-world analogue to ASP.Net MVC isn't Spring MVC, it's Grails (or Play). And Grails does have this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Spring doesn't support this at the moment, although there is a [feature request](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5779) for it. The best you can do right know is use `<spring:url>` and hardcode the path to the controller and action. `<spring:url>` will give you a context-root-relative URL.

Part of the difficulty in implementing this is that Spring gives you the power to arbitrarily define your mappings (i.e. with `@RequestMapping`). So if you're not using `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` it can be an issue.